# What condition on $x$ makes the eigenvalues real or complex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-i x& -1\\ -1&  -i x\end{bmatrix}$.  I computed the eigenvalues to get $\lambda = -ix -1$ or $-ix +1$. According to my teacher, $x$ must be greater than $1$ for the eigenvalues to be real. From the expression I see that it should be $0$. Is this wrong?

Comment: Is $x$ a real number?

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues $-ix\pm 1$ match my calculations, and one easily sees that $x=0$ does give real eigenvalues. Then the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ which has the eigenvectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ with eminently real eigenvalues. So your teacher is wrong (or you may have made a mistake while copying the problem).

Comment: That is what I thought. Now in general the matrix is to be n by n; tridiagonal, where the element in first row first column is -i*x and last row last column is -i*x. With entries in between 0 and entries above and below the main diagonal are -1. It does not seem the change. Is there an algroithm to prove this? @Henning Makholm

Answer (score 0):

Is $x$ taken to be real or complex? As your teacher (wrongly) stated $x>1$, I assume $x$ is taken to be real. However, if we allow $x$ to be complex then the general solution is $x = a i$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. This gives eigenvalues $a \pm 1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $a = 0$ corresponds to your particular solution.

Yes, it appears your teacher is not right here.